# How to create a side bar that appears on the side of screen when the app is sent to background using Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am attempting to develop a Flutter app that can be minimized to a side of the screen and remain visible over other applications (similar to [Spotify's mini-player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xftVX.jpg)). Do you have any suggestions on how I can achieve this in Flutter?

I'm new to Flutter and mobile app development. I've searched online but couldn't find much on this topic.

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Sure! Developing a Flutter app with a mini-player feature like Spotify's is a cool project to embark on, especially as a newcomer to mobile app development. Here's a suggestion on how you can achieve this:

Firstly, you'll need to utilize Flutter's Stack widget to overlay your mini-player UI over the rest of your app's content. This allows you to position your mini-player wherever you want on the screen.

Next, you'll want to handle the behavior of the mini-player when the app is minimized or moved around. One way to do this is by using Flutter's Draggable and DragTarget widgets. These widgets allow you to create draggable elements on the screen, which can be moved around by the user. You can use this functionality to implement the dragging behavior of your mini-player.

To ensure that your mini-player remains visible over other applications, you'll need to use platform-specific APIs. For Android, you can use the android_window plugin to create a floating window that stays on top of other applications. Similarly, for iOS, you can use the flutter_windowmanager plugin to achieve the same effect.

Finally, don't forget to handle user interactions with the mini-player, such as play/pause functionality, skipping tracks, and adjusting volume. You can use Flutter's built-in widgets like IconButton and Slider to implement these controls.

Overall, developing a mini-player feature in Flutter will require a combination of widget composition, platform-specific APIs, and user interface design principles. It may seem daunting at first, but with patience and perseverance, you'll be able to create a polished and functional mini-player for your Flutter app. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Ali, do you think such Flutter applications (assuming it isn't computationally expensive) would affect systems speed/RAM significantly?

Comment: this answer looks exactly like generated by ChatGPT

Comment: yes it seems so... :/